# efficient and fast KV store suitable for android phones for a million rows?

Tags: java, android

Is there a KV store that can store a million KV pairs, while performing well in an Android phone without hogging resources?

It should be able to do this fast:

```
kvstore.deleteByPrefix("image_hash_"); #a million keys have this prefix
for(... #for a million values
    kvstore.add("image_hash_"+i.toString(), "true"); #values are small
}
```

Comment: Is the embedded sqlite database not suitable?

Answer (score 2):

Your key suggests your values are large (many GBs in total)  This will cause you more problems than using a Map.

I suggest you use the file system with the name being the file name and the value being the contents of the file. You can use two levels of directories to spli the files to prevent any one directory getting too large.

---

You can use the following.

```
new File("image_hash.properties").delete(); #a million keys have this prefix
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("image_hash.properties"))
for(int i=0;i<1000*1000;i++)
    pw.println(i+"="+true);
pw.close();
```

If you are concerned about efficiency and you can only have true or false, you can write binary.

```
FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream("image_hash.flags");
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(1000*1000/8); // uses 125KB of memory.
Arrays.fill(bb.array(), (byte) -1);
fc.write(bb);
fc.close();
```

The first example uses ~14 bytes per value, the second example uses 1/8th of a byte per value.

Comment: Sorry, the values are small like `true` or current timestamp.

Comment: If you want efficiency, a binary format will help and how you encode these depends on exactly what the keys and values are. For example using String is fair ineffecient if you concerned about speed or memory.